# How to logout from appleId on expo build

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-id

I am trying to build an app using `expo build:ios` but it is always using the appleId from another project. That's not what I want. I don't know how to chance the appleId.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Expo CLI's docs:
[image]

Source: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/#expo-buildios

It looks like you could try running `expo build:ios -r` or `expo build:ios -c` to clear your apple credentials and expo credentials, respectively. If adding `-r` or `-c` doesn't work, you could try `expo build:ios --apple-id` and specify the Apple ID username you would like to log in with.